# Adding a static block to all pages (left column)

Tags: layout, cms, magento-1, static-block, phtml

I somewhat understand how to add static blocks but this issue seems a little different.  Here is the situation, I just had a year make model module installed to my magento installation, and that created two phtml files.  The installers created a CMS page that had the following callout in it to make the page.

```
{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/ymme-search.phtml"}}
```

Now my issue is that this is suppose to show up in the left column not being a page of it own.  How do I take that same callout and make it a static block and/or add it to the left column, where it is suppose to be?

Comment: Do you want it to be displayed for all pages that have the left sidebar block

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want it to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is possible with CMS configuration only and no code:**

1. Create a static block for the content to display:

   ```
   {{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/ymme-search.phtml"}}
   ```
2. Create a new widget instance (CMS > Widgets) and select your theme
   [image: screenshot (2)]
3. Add Layout Update for page "All Pages" and reference "Left Column"
   [image: screenshot (3)]
4. Select the static block from (1) in "Widget Options":
   [image: screenshot (4)]
5. Save.
6. Clean cache.

Comment: Nice I didnt know you could set this up via admin. Do you not think it is better for this to be done via local.xml in your theme from a development point of view?

Comment: @Bobadevv Depends who is responsible for maintaining it.

Comment: Yeah I guess its a perfect solution for a shop owner who doesnt have any knowledge of code or theme development, cheers for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

try adding a layout update rule in the `Layout Update XML` field under the `Design` tab of your CMS page:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="core/template" name="catalog.product.ymme_search" template="catalog/product/ymme-search.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I dont see that it added it, but now the top link (i.e. Checkout, My Account, Login) are all screwy and out of place

Comment: my site is http://southernperformanceparts.com if you want to take a look, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want this block to appear on all pages create a local.xml file inside your theme’s layout folder (app/frontend/default/your-theme/layout)

And then add the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
<reference name="left">
        <block type="core/template" name="catalog.product.ymme_search" template="catalog/product/ymme-search.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

Them flush your cache

Comment: I created the /app/design/frontend/default/car_store/layout/local.xml and added the code you gave, flushed the cache and it did not show up.  Magento is frustrating.  would someone be willing to go in there and look themselves and see if they could see the issue, If i gave you login credentials

Comment: mm that should work if you want I can take a look, Magento can be temperamental don't worry we've all been there : D